# Calculating SQL ranking based on partial data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

Given the following representative sample table;

```
Id    SupplierID    Amount     Time
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1     1             99.50      2016-02-17 13:19:21.4107347 +00:00
2     1             99.00      2016-02-17 15:00:40.1052771 +00:00
3     2             98.00      2016-02-17 15:07:07.6283091 +00:00
4     1             95.00      2016-02-17 16:40:08.4895886 +00:00
5     3             94.50      2016-02-17 16:40:18.7326269 +00:00
6     2             92.00      2016-02-17 16:40:44.0902749 +00:00
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to figure out the ranking *for each supplier for every record in the table*. So for each instance of `[Time]` I'd like to get a record for each supplier who has an entry in the table at or before that point in time, each indicating their rank at that given time. Rank is worked out over `[Amount]`, lowest being first.

So for the example above, the complete recordset I'd hope for would be as follows;

```
Rank    SupplierID    Amount     Time
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1     1             99.50      2016-02-17 13:19:21.4107347 +00:00
1     1             99.00      2016-02-17 15:00:40.1052771 +00:00
1     2             98.00      2016-02-17 15:07:07.6283091 +00:00
2     1             98.00      2016-02-17 15:07:07.6283091 +00:00
1     1             95.00      2016-02-17 16:40:08.4895886 +00:00
2     2             95.00      2016-02-17 16:40:08.4895886 +00:00
1     3             94.50      2016-02-17 16:40:18.7326269 +00:00
2     1             94.50      2016-02-17 16:40:18.7326269 +00:00
3     2             94.50      2016-02-17 16:40:18.7326269 +00:00
1     2             92.00      2016-02-17 16:40:44.0902749 +00:00
2     3             92.00      2016-02-17 16:40:44.0902749 +00:00
3     1             92.00      2016-02-17 16:40:44.0902749 +00:00
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

There can potentially be any number of `[SupplierId]`'s in the table, this example only shows three.

I would include my query attempts so far but I've spent ~8 hours on this already and haven't come up with anything halfway decent.  I'd like to avoid dynamic SQL and I feel like there's a CTE or new V12 (SQL Server 2014 equivalent) expression which might do this neatly, but I haven't been able to find it. Or perhaps it's just a basic cross-join which I can't see. (I was kinda hoping that writing this out might spark some genius in me, but no joy).

I have done my due diligence and read about recursive CTE's, pivot tables using dynamic statements and windowing functions but I'm making no headway, so any help or pointers would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I don't follow your example results. For the first time interval how did you determine the rankings? At this point Supplier 1 had 99.5 while suppliers 2 and 3 had yet to receive an amount. So I guess you decide to take supplier 1 as rank 1, but then at the second time interval you are in the exact same situation (Supplier 1 receives another amount and suppliers 2 and 3 have nothing), but your rankings change. Is it possible there is mistakes in your example set or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yeah how about some tables and sample data along with the desired output. As posted this just isn't clear at all.

Comment: @fqhv you're quite right, there was an error in the resultset. I've amended it so it should be correct. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: SQL Server has windowing functions like RANK, ROW_NUMBER etc. In the `OVER` clause you specify how to partition the data (eg by Supplier ID) and how to order the rows for ranking (eg. by Amount? ). Perhaps `RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY SupplierID ORDER BY Amount ASC) AS Rank`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - yep, thanks I've been looking at windowing functions (as stated in the question ;) but that would only give me one answer per row in the table, I'm looking for 1*X answers per row where X is the number of distinct SupplierID's in the table.

Comment: @SeanLange The first code-block contains a full example table with representative data. I've changed some of the wording to hopefully make it more clear - does that help at all?

Comment: If a supplier is not in a Time interval you simply assume the same Amount as the supplier which is present? For example at Time with .6283091 only supplier 2 is present however supplier 1 was in the interval before so you assume that his Amount is 98? How is this a correct result? Perhaps you want to SUM everything for supplier 1 until this interval and then rank them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boom. Managed to do it with a subquery. Hope it works for you!

```
select rank() over(partition by t.time order by r.amount) as [Rank],
r.supplierid, t.amount, r.amount as supplieramount, t.[time] from (
    select yt1.id, max(yt2.id) as lastamount
    from #yourtable yt1
    inner join #yourtable yt2 on yt2.id <= yt1.id
    group by yt1.id, yt2.supplierid
    ) as d
inner join #yourtable t on t.id = d.id
inner join #yourtable r on r.id = d.lastamount
order by t.id, r.amount
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after - thank you and nicely done. It works a treat and the addition of the SupplierAmount is a bonus. As an aside, I see now why it would have been more useful had I included a CREATE schema with some sample data, I will do that for any future SQL questions. Thanks for your help!